# Spring webflow 2.3.0 - How to get flowExecutionKey in form action method?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have some code in a form action class that needs to get the `flowExecutionKey` from the `RequestContext`. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. My class looks something like this:

```
public class MyFormAction extends FormAction
{
    public Event doStuff(RequestContext context)
    {
        String flowExecutionKey = ...??
        ...
    }
}
```

I know I really shouldn't need to ever get the flowExecutionKey, but I'm dealing with some legacy code that requires it. This method is being called as an entry action for a view state. I tried `context.getFlowExecutionContext().getKey()` but it returns null. `context.getFlowExecutionUrl()` also returns null. Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I was playing around with this some more, and `context.getFlowExecutionContext().getKey()` does get the the flowExecutionKey when the method is called in the `<on-render>` instead of `<on-entry>`. It is also worth noting that it works during `<on-entry>` on a later view state. The view state it's not working on is the very first view state in my flow. Is there some reason I can't get the flowExecutionKey in `<on-entry>` on the first view state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<on-entry>` callback is executing during the inital POST to the server. This will have a URL something like `http://server/myflow`. After that's complete, webflow will issue a redirect to `http://server/myflow?execution=e1s1`. It's during this call that `<on-render>` executes.

So, the reason you're not getting the key in the initial `<on-render` is that there isn't a key allocated yet. And the key that you're seeing in later `<on-render>`s is actually the key of the *previous* view.

Take a look at `RequestContext.getFlowExecutionUrl()` too - that will tell you the URL of the current request. That should shed a bit of light.